# Избежать повторной инициализации activity в onResume

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Допустим, у нас приложение для просмотра заметок с использованием фрагментов и `RecyclerView`. Заметки хранятся в БД.

Если мы напишем код фрагмента следующим образом:

```
private DataBase dataBase;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);

    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)getActivity();

    dataBase = new DataBase(activity);
    activity.changeToolbarTitle(getText(R.string.notes_tabItem).toString());

    getNotes(activity);

    return view;
}

private void getNotes(MainActivity activity){
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) activity.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new NotesAdapter(dataBase.getNotes()));
}
```

то после добавления новой записи в другой `Activity` и возврата в `MainActivity`, где в виде `RecyclerView` отображаются заметки, новой заметки не будет, пока не перезапустить приложение. Логично: ведь при возврате в `MainActivity`, где находится фрагмент, `onCreateView()` не вызывается, потому и вызова метода `getNotes(activity)`, который получает свежую информацию из БД, тоже нет.

Однако, если учесть, что после `onCreate()` всегда вызывается `onResume()`, то почему бы не поместить вызов `getNotes(activity)` в `onResume()`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private DataBase dataBase;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notes, container, false);

    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)getActivity();

    dataBase = new DataBase(activity);
    activity.changeToolbarTitle(getText(R.string.notes_tabItem).toString());

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getNotes(activity);
}
```

Один экземпляр `activity` нам всё равно нужен в `onCreateView` для других целей ; мы его и создаём. Но он же нам нужен и в `onResume()` для вызова `getNotes()`, и в сам `getNotes`, для использования `findViewByID` и создания нового `LinearLayoutManager`.

Вопрос: можно инициализировать `MainActivity` только один раз или придётся это делать заново в `onResume`? (Что касается `getNotes`, то я передал `activity` через параметр, но вероятно, это не лучшее решение).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pavel163  дал вполне разумный вариант решения проблемы. Насчет startActivityForResult можете подробно почитать тут, примерная схема как это работает там тоже есть(с единственным отличием, что у вас это будет не в активити а во фрегменте вызываться):

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-29-vyzyvaem-activity-i-poluchaem-rezultat-metod-startactivityforresult.html

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/69-urok-30-podrobnee-pro-onactivityresult-zachem-nuzhny-requestcode-i-resultcode.html

То есть другую Activity вы вызываете не через startActivity, а через startActivityForResult
и во фрагменте , код которого приведен в начале вопроса, переопределяете метод onActivityResult и вызываете в нем уже свой метод

```
MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
getNotes(activity);
```

Answer (score 2):

Сделайте переход на новую `activity` с помощью метода `startActivityForResult`. На новой `activity` отправляйте при добавление данных в БД можете добавить в `intent` все id записей которые вы добавили, и при выходе из этой активити передавать в `MainActivity`. А в методе `onActivityResult` доставать эти записи по id из бд и добавлять их в список, при этом обновлять `RecyclerView` либо по позициям добавления, либо весь список полностью

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! К сожалению, не понял, что именно нужно сделать при возврате в первую активность в методе `onActivityResult()`. Как обновить `RecyclerView`? Если весть список полностью, то нужно вызвать `getNotes() `, но в качестве аргумента должно быть что-то, что встанет на место `view` в строке `RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);`.